# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' error in AutoField table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this models.py

```
class Departamento(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Utilizador(AbstractBaseUser):
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   departamentoid = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='DepartamentoID', blank=True, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(db_column='Email', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
   nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```

And in my view I am doing

```
utilizador = Utilizador.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
dep = Departamento.objects.get(id=utilizador.departamentoid.id)
```

I am using this view in a template but I cant render the template because of this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"

Why is this happening?

Comment: you can access your dep directly use `utilizador.departamentoid`, better name the `ForeignKey` Field as departamento, since django itself will add suffix `_id` in table for Foreignkeys

Answer (score 2):

You miss id in your:

`utilizador = Utilizador.objects.get(id=request.user.id)`

But it's actually better to do:

`dep = utilizador.departamentoid`

Comment: then check your ```request.user```, probably authentication problems

Comment: ```id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)``` this field might cause problems, remove it since id is generated automatically

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you get object here

```
utilizador = Utilizador.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
```

Then also make sure `utilizador` have `departamentoid`.
Because if an object doesn't have a property then you can't access it attribute.
That means if `utilizador` doesn't have `departamentoid` so you have not to access the `id` by `departamentoid.id`

Comment: yes, I am sure it has departamentoid. I tried your way and returns the same

Comment: Just print this `utilizador.departamentoid`. See what it returns

Comment: it prints Departamento object (1)

Comment: I dont know the magic but since I print it somehow it started working